# How to create pagination based on column data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a view in mvc5 app to show only data from the current year. I would like that when the user clicks on arrow at bottom of page, the table data should change to show data from previous year. What is the best approach to do this? Should I load the entire table and then select the appropriate data based on user clicking or through ajax?

I have researched about pagination, but all the research shows how to create pages based on number of rows, I would like to split the table based on  data and with the user clicking previous or next(not page numbers).

This is my view. I want to paginate based on the year in actualcompleted date.
What is the best approach?

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.AllCompletedAccToMonth)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApartmentBlock.BuildingID)
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApartmentBlock.Address)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apartment.ApartmentNumber)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RenovationDetails)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact.CompanyName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActualCompletedDate)
                    </td>
```

Comment: You could group by the year of the date column and paginate based on the number of groups you have. But without your code, we can't help you

Comment: *"Should I load the entire table and then select the appropriate data based on user clicking or through ajax?"* - They both sound like potentially reasonable approaches given the information known to the question.  Why not give one a try and see how it goes?  If you encounter a problem we may be able to help with that.

Comment: @marco can you show me an example of how to paginate by the number of groups. I am unsure how to do so, because the number of groups will change as the years move on